# How to make interrupt run only in ISR without Running the main code

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I am working on a piece of code that counts pulses while the microcontroller is in deepsleep. I would like the external interrupt to just run the ISR which just increments a counter. I however noticed that data is being transmitted whenever pulses are generated instead if the specific interval I have set in code. Below is my code that illustrates what I would like to do.

```
#include "LowPower.h"

const uint8_t btn =2;
volatile int power = 0;
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(btn), count, FALLING);

}

void loop() {
   Serial.print("Power: ");
 Serial.println(power);
  delay(50);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF); // Put Arduino in Sleep mode 8 times 8 seconds
  }

}
void count() {
  power += 1;
}
```

From the code above I would expect to see The serial statement being printed roughly just over a minute each time but not whenever an interrupt is generated. Is there something I am missing, thank you.

Comment: You also have a big bug in your code where you print power in loop.  That variable needs protection in a critical section since it is also accessed from the ISR.  What happens if the ISR changes the value in between accessing the two bytes of the int?  You have to turn interrupts off, copy the value, turn them back on, and then print the copy.

Comment: What is creating the pulses?  What are the counts you are seeing?  When you get the interrupt it will wake up the micro.  So if you are getting a bunch of pulses or a switch is bouncing and giving you 8 or more pulses then you'll see it getting printed more often because it isn't sleeping the whole 8 seconds.

Comment: If that is the case you could try to put the `delay` inside the `for` looping, giving kind of a debouncing effect.

Comment: I am using the blink sketch from another Arduino that is blinking at a second interval. I have a 10K resistor hooked up between pin 2 and ground to act as pull down. I am most curious about what happens when in an external interrupt fires. should the  main loop run even of the interrupt is attached to an ISR?

Comment: Then after 8 blinks it will leave your `for` loop, as each blink is kicking the Arduino outside of powerDown.

Comment: No, the loop doesn’t run in the interrupt.  The interrupt wakes up the mcu and then loop runs as normal once it’s awake.

Comment: The interrupt is kicking the `powerDown` out, so at each interrupt it is going the next iteration of the `for` loop. So one would expect comm on Serial every approximately eight seconds. If you are seeing something each time there might be something else.

Comment: This makes sense. I will do more tests and see what is going on and even spacing out the pulses

Answer (score 0):

From the [this](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-sleep-modes-and-how-to-use-them-to-reduce-power-consumption) using `LowPower`, it would seem that Serial communication could be used to exit the mode `powerDown` (which is good, as you do not want the Serial buffer to get full). It is also the case of interrupts unfortunately.

That would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: That would be for incoming data though.  This doesn't appear to be receiving anything.

Comment: Yeah, the ISR is what's waking it up.  The question is how many times is that interrupt firing in the 64 seconds he wants to sleep.

Comment: The ISR is only for incrementing a counter (power variable) for each interrupt occurrence. My interest is have the counter just be incremented when the ISR runs without running the loop untill The sleep duration is over in the forloop

Comment: Maybe put `LowPower.powerDown` in the interrupt maybe? Do not know if that works…

Comment: If you go back to sleep inside the ISR be sure to leave yourself a way out.

Comment: I think tha proper way is to have the sleep code within the main section and just leave the ISR for the interrupt. I will keep trying with other architectures like stm to see if the behavior is similar to avr.